# How to programmatically know if a module is a Core module?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I've got a list of modules used in an application. I would like to test if these modules are part of the Perl core (if they need to be installed during the application deployment on a fresh server environment).

Is the [Module::CoreList module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/CoreList.html) is an appropriate tool to test this and if not, how should I deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will tell you if a module is a core module for the version of Perl being used.

```
use Module::CoreList qw( );

if (exists $Module::CoreList::version{ $] }{'CGI'}) {
   print "yes\n";
} else {
   print "no\n";
}
```

Note that it will only work for the "main" module of a distribution.

Comment: Thanx. For better understanding I will add that `$]` is a representation of the Perl version: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$]